# What's the probability distribution for an unfair die given the die's density?

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, physics, dice

Suppose you have a smooth positive real-valued function $f$ defined on the unit cube $[0,1]^3$. Think of the unit cube as a six-sided die where, without loss of generality, the 1-side faces the positive $x$-direction, the 2-side faces the positive $y$-directions, the 3-side faces the positive $z$ direction, and opposite sides sum to 7. The function $f$ describes the density of the die at a point. What is the probability distribution of the result of rolling this die?

---

**Context**: I thought of this question while bored in a teacher meeting. It seems like a pretty natural question, but couldn't find it on this site (searching for "unfair die" or "unfair dice" returns only a pile of poorly-titled questions, in case someone has motivation to do housekeeping). Hopefully the intended question is clear. *Feel free to edit it you think it needs clarification*. Especially feel free to edit the tags; this is not near my area of expertise. Idk how appropriate the [physics](/questions/tagged/physics) tag is.

Comment: [The reverse question, "given the probabilities can you construct the die density", can be found here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4302234/167197)

Comment: With a biased die, how you roll it may make a difference

Comment: @Henry Like, you mean whether you drop the die straight down, versus throwing it along a table or something? That makes sense. That would make this question not-well-defined unless there is some way to account for (normalize for?) that fact.